# RegEX for matching particular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use a Regex check instead of

```
if( actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath == "/api/v1/token")
```

using something like:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/api/v1/token");
```

and matching not only v1, but also v2, v3, v4 and so on...

```
if(rgx. actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.isMatch){
//then do further actions

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the solution to your problem.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/api/v[0-9][0-9]*/token")
```

Please note as you did not specify if you needed just v1, v2, v3 and v4 or any numbered suffix, I have assumed the latter.

Edit 01:
As a kind friend pointed out this can be achieved by using this as well which is I guess a better way of doing it

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/api/v[0-9]+?/token")
```

Edit 02:
This will eliminate v0 as required initially by the person who asked the question

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/api/v[1-9][0-9]*/token")
```

Comment: @Tanmay No you can't. [0-9] is not a range, it means number

Comment: ok thanks so what if 9999 wil caome everytime i have to change this ?

Comment: You don't need to add [0-99]. The syntax mentioned does it for you. for example you want a v99 what the syntax will do is firstly match the first 9 of v99 to the specified range [0-9]. Then next it will again match next 9 with the next range specified by [0-9]* which means the numbers in this range can occur 0 or more time (how many more is not significant.)

Comment: Not, with this you are saying that you want 1 number, eventually followed by others. This will match v1 like v9999. Even if in this answer, using 2 [0-9] is useless.

Comment: /api/v1/token like right now i am having version v1 but it will go like version v999 which wil not gona possible but i want to what if

Comment: @Tanmay Regex specified is actually like this [0-9] means any number between 0 and 9 but only once. Then [0-9]* means any number between 0 and 9 but infinite number of times. So repeating digits between 0-9 you can create any number. Hope this explains it.

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma actually, v[0-9]* match "v1" like "v". * operator allows 0 occurence. +? for at least one to infinit. With this you don't need the double [0-9]

Comment: @Tanmay Think of numbers as series of digits between 0-9. This will help you understand the concept better.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois You are right but what I have written is essentially the same as operator +?... [0-9][0-9]* first one is a must occur and next ones can occur 0 or more times. So this sums up to once or more time which is equivalent of +?...

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma Yes it's the same, but since Regex is eating lot of resources to compute, it's more efficient to do less operation possible.

Comment: Sorry guys  i am confused which one should i use [0-9][0-9]* or [0-9]+? for clarification v0 never comes it will start with v1 only

Comment: Okay I am editing the answer so it helps other out as well.

Comment: @Tanmay Both will give you v0.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois See now eliminating v0 can't be achieved by the use of operator +?..... As [1-9]+? would eliminate 0 altogether meaning it will not allow 10, 100, 100, 101 i.e. any number having 0 in it.

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma Yes, with this update it won't manage the op needs

Answer (score 3):

This should works. It will match every version number and need at least one number.

```
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^/api/v[0-9]+?/token$");

    /api/v1/token => ok
    /api/v2560/token => ok
    /api/v/token => ko
```

You can check for more complexe regex and test it [here](https://regex101.com/)

**UPDATE**

In order to eliminate v0 like op asked in comment, see marked answer edit02.

Comment: AFAIK you dont have to escape `/` for c#

Answer (score 3):

```
 Regex rgx = new Regex("^\/api\/v[1234]\/token$");
if(rgx.IsMatch(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath)){
//then do further actions

}
```

Comment: I think you should wrap the regex in in `^$`

Comment: "^$\/api\/v[1234]\/token" in this way